# Delphi toolbar button to switch between unit and form view disapppeared?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

Two buttons on the view toolbar in Delphi disappeared and I can't get them back. One of those buttons is the one to switch between code/unit and the design/form view which I use all the time. The keyboard shortcut for switching (F12) still works, but I have one of those pesky media keyboards where you have to press a function key to access F-keys, so I'd really like to get that toolbar button back.

[image]

I tried resetting all the toolbars and their contents, and I see space where the buttons *should* be, but they aren't there. In the customize dialog for the toolbar, the commands don't seem to even be there anymore.

[image]

I tried doing a "repair" re-installation of Delphi, but even that didn't fix it. Has anyone else had this happen before, or have ideas on how to repair or reset my IDE?

edit: perhaps it's worth mentioning the menu options to toggle between code/unit and design/form view are also missing.

Comment: try running IDE in 'clean' mode. Command line, "bds.exe -rNewRegistryKeyName"
If it would work, then something changes in HKCU registry branch for IDE and perhaps has to be reset.

Comment: I understand the difference between "code and design view", but what is the difference between "code and unit" view? The code *is* the unit.

Comment: that was a typo, it should have read unit and design view

Comment: @KenWhite: if that would be the case, wouldn't that just gray out the button?

Comment: @whosrdaddy: Yeah, the use of both was confusing, because it makes it sound like two different things. :-) Thanks. (Deleted the rest; a quick check of D2007's IDE shows the presence/absence of the .dfm doesn't affect appearance; it just changes whether enabled or not. I was testing when you posted your last comment.)

Comment: quit delphi, rename following registry key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\11.0\Toolbars and start up again. See if that helps

Comment: Neither running the IDE with the clean mode parameter nor renaming the toolbars registry key had any effect.

Comment: Did you try selecting the View toolbar (in the Toolbars tab in the above dialog) and pressing 'Reset'?  Presumably F12 doesn't work either

Comment: @Rob As I mentioned in my post, pressing F12 to switch views does still continue to work but resetting the toolbar had no effect.

Comment: Looks like you hit a bug in the IDE?  Very weird.

Comment: Looks like some code (plugin? ) switches http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.ActnList.TAction.Visible to false...

Comment: Hmm, I have a pretty vanilla install, no plugins that change the IDE around. I do have Indy components and Cool Tray Icon components installed but neither of those should have any affect. For what it's worth, I still have not found a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As best I can tell, this problem (missing view unit/form button and menu option) could possibly be a limitation of the starter edition of Delphi (this forum post: https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=83324 ) seems to indicate an XE3 user with starter edition has the same missing buttons on their toolbar.

I did discover at the bottom of the screen there are tabs to switch between code, design, and history, which does at least give a mouse-based workaround to toggling between the views without having to expand the file view and click the right pas/dfm file. And the F12 keyboard shortcut does still work as well.